# How to start a python app through supervisord as non root

Tags: python, supervisord

I am running a python flask app and have setup supervisord to restart the python app automatically when it crashes.

I want the python app to be running as non root user. But when supervisord starts the python app, it runs it as root.

How can i make sure my python app always runs without root privilages?

Answer (score 1):

Configuring user options:

```
[program:flask_app]
directory = ''
command = ''
autostart = true
startsecs = 5
autorestart = true
startretries = 3
user = username
```